# Check if integer is multiple of 8

Tags: c++

Hi i'm new to c++ so i'm not sure if this is a really silly question. Basically i'm using a c++ custom action project to interact with my MSI installer. I get a property that my user will have entered, it is an integer. I need to ensure that this is a multiple of 8 and i'm not sure how to go about this. Obviously if it can be divided by 8 it is a multiple but I am not sure how to capture if there is a remainder. Any help would be appreciated or even point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: I think you simply need to use the % operator.
   bool isMultipleOf8 = (value % 8) == 0;

Comment: You need the modulo operator (`%`) if this is non-zero, it's not a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the "modulo" operator, which gives the remainder from division:

```
if (n % 8 == 0) {
    // n is a multiple of 8
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the "modulo" or "integer remainder operator" `%`:

```
int a = ....;
if (a % 8 == 0 ) {
  // a is amultiple of 8
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use operator %

```
if ( num % 8 == 0 )
{
    // num is multple of 8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking only the last `3` digits of a number does the job.
Even if you are given a huge number in the form of a `string` where the `%` operating is not useful you can check if only the last 3 digits are divisible by 8 then the whole number is divisible by `8`.

Answer (score 1):

For unsigned integers the three least significant bits are always zero for a multiple of 8, so a bitwise & on these bits should be false. For signed (twos complement) this is only true if the integer is positive, so beware if your input is being stored as signed or not (do you want to accept negative numbers as input). Also note the three least significant bits are zero for zero itself, so think if you want your check to be true when someone inputs zero. From your question it doesn't seem like your code has to be optimized so just use modulo.

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone was using bit operation

```
bool f( int x){
return !(x & 7);
}
```

It was said this approach has some problem, but I am not quite sure.